# popViewController after dismiss Modal VC Swift

Tags: swift, swift5, modalviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I want to `popViewController` after I dismiss a modalVC. However my code is not working. What is wrong?

```
func showMessage(withTitle title: String, message: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { (_) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
        
        alert.addAction(alertAction)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I have also tried this:

```
  let controller = ViewController()             
controller?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Shouldn´t this be `alert.dismiss(....`?

Comment: You should use a delegate

Comment: Check if your current `view controller` is pushed by `navigationController?.pushViewController`. I tested it in a controller that has `navigationController` and it worked fine. Try printing `navigationController?.viewControllers` to see the current state.

Comment: "nil" is what I get when printing this ..

Comment: This means that you don't have a `UINavigationController` to work with. You have to wrap the VC in the navigation controller for it to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I created two viewcontrollers vc1 and vc2. vc1 has a navigation controller and vc2 is pushed on top of vc1 is the navigation stack. In vc2 the alert is shown and on tap of ok button vc2 is popped and removed from navigation stack. Works fine for me.
Code for vc1:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecViewController") as? SecViewController ?? SecViewController(), animated: true)
}
}
```

Code for vc2:

```
class SecViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showMessage(withTitle: "title", message: "Message")
}


func showMessage(withTitle title: String, message: String) {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { (_) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    alert.addAction(alertAction)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```